# Can someone help me understand this "family of sets"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been trying to understand what this "family of sets" really is all day and I just can't wrap my head around it. it goes like this:
$\{A_n\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ such that $A_n \subseteq{\mathbb{N}}$ for every $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$.
At first, I thought that this "family of sets" is practically equal to $P(\mathbb{N})$ but then I also think it might be just a random subset of $\mathbb{N}$ for every different $n$ like as long as $A_n \subseteq{\mathbb{N}}$ then it is counted as part of the family of sets. Can someone give me an idea of what this family of sets represents?
for more context, the question continued to define $D=\{n\in{\mathbb{N}} : n\notin{A_n}\}$ and then continues to ask multiple questions such as: define the family of sets $\{A_n\}_{n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ such that $D=\emptyset$

Comment: We need more context to say for sure, but it appears that $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is simply some countably infinite collection of subsets of $\Bbb N$. It certainly isn’t the entire power set of $\Bbb N$, since that is uncountable.

Comment: you are right i made a typo

Comment: There are many families $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ for which $D=\varnothing$. $D=\varnothing$ if and only if $n\in A_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so for instance we could let $A_n=\{n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. We could also let $A_n=\Bbb N$ for each $n\in N$. Another fairly simple possibility is to let $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k\ge n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$; $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k\le n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ is yet another.

Comment: thank you for the explanation

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this

> it might be just a random subset of $\mathbb{N}$ for every different
> $n$ like as long as $A_n \subseteq \mathbb{N}$

is correct.

Suppose you have such a sequence. For definitiness, imagine that it starts as
$$
A_1 = \{1,2,3\}, A_2 = \text{the odd numbers}, A_3= \text{primes}, A_4 = \{3\}, \ldots
$$

Then the set $D$ for this particular sequence starts with
$$
D = \{2, 4, \ldots \}
$$
since $2 \not \in A_2$ and $4 \not \in A_4$ while $1   \in A_1$ and $3  \in A_3$.

Now you might be able to continue with the "multiple questions" that follow.

Note: I suspect that this exercise is leading up to an argument showing that the list $\{A_n\}$ cannot be all of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.